# is there a limit to how many drives I can connect to my Mac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, firewire

I am on Mac Book Pro running OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 and I use a lot of drives for my personal data and data from clients (and every drive has a redundant drive constantly being updated in case of drive failure).

Besides the internal SSD drive and Might Drive SSD Flash drive inside my SD slot, I have 8 external drives. 5 of them are all powered drives connected via daisy-chained FireWire 800 cables that originate from the Thunderbolt port with a TB to FW800 adapter. 4 of them are USB drives (one is a powered USB 2.0 drive and the other 3 are self-powered USB 3.0 drives that are connected to the computer via a 3.5A powered USB 3.0 hub).

Today I had to connect another drive from a client. This drive is a self-powered drive that has USB 3.0 and FW800 connections. Needless to say the drive works if plugged in by itself with either of those connections but as soon as I plug the drive in with my existing drives all in it either doesn't mount at all (if I plug it in on the USB hub via USB 3.0) or it makes the entire daisy-chain of FW800 drives disconnect (and I get an error saying I improperly disconnected the drives). I have drive putting the drive at the top or at the end of the chain of drives but I get the same result every time. Even though I specifically bought a USB 3.0 powered 3.5A amp to avoid issues of powering multiple drives, I thought it might be a power issue, but when this happens on the FireWire 800 chain and all the drives on that chain are powered by walmart adapters I began to question if there is a limit to connecting drives to a computer.

Any information on this would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Even though the drives are powered by external power bricks, some of the power is still supplied by the host USB/Firewire device, which means thereis indeed a limit to the amount of USB/Firewire devices you can connect to a given USB/Firewire Hub.  Since you have a laptop there really are not solutions to expand the number of HUBs your system has.

Comment: shouldn't the extra power be provided by the power supplies? is there a way to see how much power is available and/or needed? is there a way to increase the power or any other way to add more drives? is there some official number on how many drives can be on a FireWire or a USB3 connection?

Comment: The extra power required to power the device is provided by the power supplies, but not all the power, and a single USB Hub can only handle so much power.  USB can handle 256 devices per hub, how many that actually ends up being, depends on the power draw of each device.  Firewire is similar, I don't recall the number, its documented on Wikipedia though.

Comment: It might be wiser to invest in a thunderbolt/firewire storage array - much cleaner and easier than this mess of daisy chaining

Comment: I have multiple hard drives for a reason (some I have to take to different locations to work and then every removable drive has a mirror drive for backup) so a TB raid solution won't work for me